# Transition / Fingerprint existing Paperclip files to use MD5 Checksum

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

I set up the correct configuration and it works for new attachments. But I want to add a fingerprint to existing paperclip attachments. Just reprocessing and saving them again doesn't do the trick. Is there any way to run reprocess! that also generates the fingerprint and renames the file? Using rails 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Each attachment has a `generate_fingerprint` method which will calculate the fingerprint:

```
fingerprint = photo.attachment.generate_fingerprint(photo.attachment)
```

Once you know the fingerprint, you can write a migration that calculates it as above, updates the model to store the fingerprint, and renames each existing file to match whatever new path hash you prefer.